# ostrio:files how do I remove images programmatically?

Tags: meteor

I have successfully added ostrio:files to my Meteor project. Upload and displaying all works. Now my problem is, that I have no idea how to delete Images from the server again. Deleting the corresponding item in the Images collection does not seem to delete the file (at least not on localhost). What is the best way to go about this?

I also checked the [documentation](https://github.com/VeliovGroup/Meteor-Files) but could not find anything about deleting files again.

Comment: Can you please add a short code example of how you intend to delete the file?

Comment: that is the problem, I don't even have a starting point,  because I relied on the example code. I googled around and could not find any method one could call or so, that does this. Initial thought was to just delete the corresponding item in the Images collection of MongoDB, but that does not seem to trigger deleting the (much larger) actual file.

Comment: "but that does not seem to trigger deleting the (much larger) actual file" -> So you have written some code, indeed. Please add it to your post. No matter if it's working or not, good or bad. If we can reproduce your problem we may be able to help you in solving it.